# Show <li> element when clicked on another

Tags: jquery

i have some trouble in make this working.

Basicaly, i have 2 Unordered List. I need to click in some link on first list, and display yours equivalent in the second list... but.. why i don't know, this doen't work.

My CSS:

```
.banner_list{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .banner_list li{
        display: none;
    }
```

My structure:

```
<div id="tec_medals">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">ACTIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="flex">FLEX</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="mais_alto">MAIS ALTO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="massagem">MASSAGEM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sense">SENSE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="banner" class="banner_tecnologia">
    <ul class="banner_list">
        <li class="active">ACTIVE OK</li>
        <li class="flex">FLEX OK</li>
        <li class="mais_alto">MAIS ALTO OK</li>
        <li class="massagem">MASSAGEM OK</li>
        <li class="sense">SENSE OK</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and my script:

```
$('.banner_list li').first().css('display', 'block');

$('#tec_medals a').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tec_atual = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(tec_atual);
    $('.banner_list li').fadeOut();
    $('.banner_list').find('class', tec_atual).css('display','block').fadeIn();
});
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HF8Z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4HF8Z/4/).

try this:

```
$('.banner_list li').first().show();

$('#tec_medals a').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.banner_list li').hide();
    $('.banner_list').find('.' + $(this).attr('class')).show(); // Change here
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will only work if the `a`s in the first list each only have a single class ever.

Comment: some way to add some transition between each other?

Comment: @Preston simplest way is to add a number of miliseconds to the show and hide calls

Comment: @Preston try .show(500); or increase to add more effect as u needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `.find()` like that; find your class selector just prepending `.` to your class name `tec_atual` and you're done:

Try with this

```
$('#tec_medals a').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tec_atual = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(tec_atual);
    $('.banner_list li').fadeOut();
    $('.banner_list').find('.' + tec_atual).css('display','block').fadeIn(); // Change here
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4HF8Z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `find` here.you can do like this:

```
$('.banner_list li').first().css('display', 'block');

$('#tec_medals a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tec_atual = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(tec_atual);
    $('.banner_list li').fadeOut();
    $(".banner_list ." + tec_atual).css('display', 'block').fadeIn();//change here
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/4HF8Z/7/)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a more accurate way**. Also `.css('display', 'block')` is unnecessary when you are chaining `fadeIn()`.  [Fiddle is available as well](http://jsfiddle.net/4HF8Z/8/).

```
$('.banner_list li').first().css('display', 'block');

$('#tec_medals a').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var tec_atual = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(tec_atual);
    $('.banner_list li').fadeOut();
    $('.banner_list').find("li."+tec_atual).fadeIn();
});
```